# Shell script throws a not found error when run from a sh file. But if entered manually the commands work

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I'm trying to use the following script to generate a sitemap for my website. When I run it as `sh thsitemap.sh` I get an error like this and creates an empty sitemap.xml file:

```
thsitemap.sh: 22: thsitemap.sh: [[: not found
thsitemap.sh: 42: thsitemap.sh: [[: not found
thsitemap.sh: 50: thsitemap.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

But as the same user `root` when I manually copy and paste these lines on the terminal, it works without any error and the sitemap.xml file have all the urls. What's the problem? How can I fix this?

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################################
# modified version of original http://media-glass.es/ghost-sitemaps/
# for ghost.centminmod.com
# http://ghost.centminmod.com/ghost-sitemap-generator/
##############################################
url="techhamlet.com"
webroot='/home/leafh8kfns/techhamlet.com'
path="${webroot}/sitemap.xml"
user='leafh8kfns'       # web server user
group='leafh8kfns'      # web server group

debug='n' # disable debug mode with debug='n'
##############################################
date=`date +'%FT%k:%M:%S+00:00'`
freq="daily"
prio="0.5"
reject='.rss, .gif, .png, .jpg, .css, .js, .txt, .ico, .eot, .woff, .ttf, .svg, .txt'
##############################################
# create sitemap.xml file if it doesn't exist and give it same permissions
# as nginx server user/group
if [[ ! -f "$path" ]]; then
    touch $path
    chown ${user}:${group} $path
fi

# check for robots.txt defined Sitemap directive
# if doesn't exist add one
# https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669
if [ -f "${webroot}/robots.txt" ]; then
SITEMAPCHECK=$(grep 'Sitemap:' ${webroot}/robots.txt)
    if [ -z "$SITEMAPCHECK" ]; then
    echo "Sitemap: http://${url}/sitemap.xml" >> ${webroot}/robots.txt
    fi
fi
##############################################
echo "" > $path

# grab list of site urls
list=`wget -r --delete-after $url --reject=${reject} 2>&1 |grep "\-\-"  |grep http | grep -v 'normalize\.css' | awk '{ print $3 }'`

if [[ "$debug" = [yY] ]]; then
    echo "------------------------------------------------------"
    echo "Following list of urls will be submitted to Google"
    echo $list
    echo "------------------------------------------------------"
fi

# put list into an array
array=($list)

echo "------------------------------------------------------"
echo ${#array[@]} "pages detected for $url" 
echo "------------------------------------------------------"

# formatted properly according to
# https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35738
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">" > $path

echo ' 
   ' >> $path;
   for ((i=0;i<${#array[*]};i++)); do
echo "<url>
    <loc>${array[$i]:0}</loc>
    <lastmod>$date</lastmod>
    <changefreq>$freq</changefreq>
    <priority>$prio</priority>
</url>" >> $path
   done
echo "" >> $path
echo "</urlset>" >> $path

# notify Google
# URL encode urls as per https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669
if [[ "$debug" = [nN] ]]; then
    wget  -q --delete-after http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2F${url}%2Fsitemap.xml

    rm -rf ${url}
else
    echo "wget  -q --delete-after http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=http%3A%2F%2F${url}%2Fsitemap.xml"

    echo "rm -rf ${url}"
fi
echo "------------------------------------------------------"

exit 0
```

Comment: How you run the script?

Comment: @Gnouc sh script.sh

Comment: Try: `bash script.sh`, calling `sh` make `bash` switch to posix mode. I remember this type of question has been answered. You can refer to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44836/when-sh-is-a-symlink-to-bash-or-dash-bash-limits-itself-to-posix-compliance-so

Comment: [[ is a bash feature. Change /bin/sh to /bin/bash

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Run the script either as:

```
bash script.sh
```

or just:

```
./script.sh
```

When `bash` is run using the name `sh`, it disables most of its extensions, such as the `[[` testing operator.

Since you have the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line, you don't need to specify the shell interpreter explicitly on the command line. Running the script as a command will use that line to find the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Both your...  `if [[ debug = "...“ ]] ; then...` commands are incorrect they should read...

```
if [ "debug" = "Y" -o "debug" = "y" ]
```

Comment: No, the code is valid bash, just not valid sh.

Comment: Error 1, line 22 some issue with [[.

Comment: @rhubarbdog If the has #!/bin/sh then your answer may work, if the file has #!/bin/bash the if [[ debug = "...“ ]] should not a problem

Comment: I think it's valid to point out that `[[` doesn't exist in shell, but instead there's `[`. Thanks!