# Shell : Checking if a string contains a specified character

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/sh

TMP=$(cd Folder && ls)

for name in $TMP; do

  if [[ "${name}" != *"a"* -a ${name} == *"b"* ]] ;then
   echo $name
  fi

done
```

I was trying to output the names that has no 'a' in it but 'b' instead .
This is the error that I got :

```
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
./aufg7.sh: 6: [[: not found
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229551/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-bash/20460402#20460402

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're using a pattern match in `[[ ... ]]` in a script executed by `/bin/sh` which does not support these types of tests. See also the question entitled [Shell script throws a not found error when run from a sh file. But if entered manually the commands work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155838/shell-script-throws-a-not-found-error-when-run-from-a-sh-file-but-if-entered-ma)

The other issue is that you are combining the output of `ls` into a single string before splitting it into words on spaces, tabs and newlines, and applying filename globbing to the generated words.  You then loop over the result of this.

Instead:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

cd Folder || exit 1

for name in *b*; do
    [ -e "$name" ] || [ -L "$name" ] || continue
    case $name in (*a*) ;; (*) printf '%s\n' "$name"; esac
done
```

This loops over all files in the `Folder` directory that have the letter `b` in them, and then prints the ones of these that do not contain an `a`.  The test for the `a` character is done using `case ... esac`.  The `*a*` pattern matches an `a` character in the filename if there is one, in which case nothing happens.  The `printf` statements is in the "default case" which gets executed if there is no `a` in the string.

The tests with `-e` and `-L` are there to make sure that we catch the edge case where the loop pattern doesn't match anything.  In that case, the pattern will remain unexpanded, so to make sure that we can distinguish between an unexpanded pattern and an actual existing file, we test with `-e`.  The `-L` test is to catch the further edge case of a symbolic link that has the same name as the loop pattern, but that does not point to anywhere valid. The `bash` code below does not need this because it uses the `nullglob` shell option instead (unavailable in `/bin/sh`).

Running the loop over the expansion of the `*b*` pattern instead of whatever `ls` outputs has the benefit that this also is able to deal with filenames containing spaces, tabs, newlines and filename globbing characters (the filenames are never put into a single string that we then try to iterate over).

In the `bash` shell, you could do the same with a `[[ ... ]]` pattern matching test, like you tried to do yourself:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd Folder || exit 1

shopt -s nullglob

for name in *b*; do
    [[ $name != *a* ]] && printf '%s\n' "$name"
done
```

See also:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 6):

To print the filenames in `Folder` that contain `b` and not `a`, in `zsh` and its `~` (*except* / *and-not*) glob operator:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- Folder/(*b*~*a*)(N:t)
```

(remove the `N` (for `nullglob`, if you'd rather want an error be reported where there's no matching file).

In `ksh93` (the shell that introduced that `[[...]]` operator (which is not part of the standard `sh` syntax) and its `&` (*and*) and `!(...)` (*not*) operators:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
(
  CDPATH= cd Folder &&
    set -- ~(N)@(*b*&!(*a*)) &&
    (($# > 0)) &&
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```

With the `bash` shell (which like `zsh` has also copied ksh's `[[...]]` operator), using `extglob` to support ksh88 glob operators and `nullglob` to get the effect of zsh's `N` glob qualifier or `ksh93`'s `~(N)` glob operator and some double negation with `|` (*or*) to achieve *and*:

```
#! /bin/bash -
(
  shopt -s extglob nullglob
  cd ./Folder &&
    set -- !(!(*b*)|*a*) &&
    (($# > 0)) &&
    printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```

In standard `sh` syntax:

```
#! /bin/sh -
(
  CDPATH= cd Folder || exit
  set -- [*]b[*] *b*
  [ "$1/$2" = '[*]b[*]/*b*' ] && exit # detect the case where the pattern
                                      # expands to itself because there's
                                      # no match as there's no nullglob
                                      # equivalent in sh
  shift
  for i do
    case $i in
      (*a*) ;;
      (*) set -- "$@" "$i"
    esac
    shift
  done
  [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf '%s\n' "$@"
)
```

Note that the solutions that use `cd` won't work if you have read access to `Folder` but not search access to it.

More generally, to answer the general question of how to check if a string contains another one in `sh`, best is with the `case` construct which is how you do pattern matching in `sh`. You could even use a helper function:

```
contains()
  case "$1" in
    (*"$2"*) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
```

To use as if:

```
if contains foobar o; then
  echo foobar contains o
fi
```

```
if ! contains foobar z; then
  echo foobar does not contain o
fi
```

```
if
  contains "$file" b &&
    ! contains "$file" a
then
  printf '%s\n' "$file contains b and not a "
fi
```

Comment: `!(!(*b*)|*a*)` is wild. Also works: `*([^a])b*([^a])`